# Use $_GET for get id for my link

Tags: php, get

lets say i have a link like that

http://www.example.com/d8ed54

d8ed54 is the id

How i can use $_GET to echo the id

Thank you

**Update........**

Not possible in my case to use .htaccess RewriteRule because it's already have a one for all the script links..i can't play on it.

However the link http://www.example.com/d8ed54 will work without 404

I need something with php

Comment: You need `mod_rewrite` for that.

Comment: by using .htaccess RewriteRule (.*) index.php?id=$1

Comment: Impossible with no .htaccess, the only solution i see is a link like this : http://www.example.com/?/d8ed54/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the following in htaccess

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?id=$1
```

and then you can use `$_GET['id']` to get whatever is passed after the /

you can also do this without $_GET and without any extra additions to your htaccess, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the same piece of information.

```
$id = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: The problem is `http://www.example.com/d8ed54` would return 404 without a rewrite rule. How do you get your script to run in the first place?

Comment: 'without any extra additions to your htaccess'

Comment: @user2005646: updated the answer, use `$id = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Answer (score 0):

Without using mod_rewrite Apache (Assuming you use Apache) will look for a file or directory named d8ed54. I'm afraid it cannot be done without mod_rewrite.